# Using one method for two different objects within a separate class?

Tags: java

Here is the exact line from my homework:

> Write a Java class named BankAccount that can be used to keep track of a player's current balance. Each instance of a BankAccount has private instance variables for the name of the account holder (a String) and the balance (an int). The class has five public methods to construct a BankAccount, to get the value of a BankAccount, to display a BankAccount, to deposit to a BankAccount, and to withdraw from a BankAccount.

My question is, when I construct the instance variables for the balance, can I just use one or would I have to create two separate instance variables for balance, one for player1 and another for player2? I have to return a balance in the getValue method.

Basically I am asking if when i call the getValue method in another class, can I set that method to two separate players and have it return two separate balances?

Oh and here is another section of homework in case it helps you understand my question:

> Create a driver class called PlayDice that uses the methods in the Die and BankAccount classes. It should create two BankAccount objects for the two players and then allow the players to play as many games of dice as they wish. You are free to decide what it means for a player to win or to lose.

Comment: Ah! You just overwrote the edit I did.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated. Please don't select tags at random.

Comment: If you read the instructions you provided second, it should answer your question. "Create two BankAccount objects for the two players". Each BankAccount object will be separate, when you want the balance, you will call the object's balance method. It will only return it's balance, to retrieve another objects balance you would need to call that object's balance. ie: `player1.getBalance(); player2.getBalance()

Answer (score 0):

The class is a template which specifies placeholders for data, and logic for manipulating that data. You create as many actual objects, based on that template, as you like. So if you create player1 and player2, they are both using the same class, so you only code 1 class. Each object (player1 and player2) will have their own copies of balance, etc.  When you invoke a method, like getBalance() on player1, it will only return the balance for player1 object.